# Keep getting error when trying to upload image to Firebase Storage in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The image is not uploading getting the error is "The server has terminated the upload session User does not have permission to access this object". I change my security rules of Storage but again got the same error

```
import 'dart:io';
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Image? childImage;
  TextEditingController childNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController childAgeController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController childDiagnosisController = TextEditingController();
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
  FocusNode _childNameFocus = FocusNode();
  FocusNode _childAgeFocus = FocusNode();
  FocusNode _childDiagnosisFocus = FocusNode();
  String buttonText = 'Image';

  String get _childName => childNameController.text;

  void _nameEditingComplete() {
    final newFocus = widget.nameValidator.isValid(_childName)
        ? _childAgeFocus
        : _childNameFocus;
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(newFocus);
  }

  Future<void> writeChildrenToDb(
      String parentUid,
      String childUid,
      String childNameInput,
      String childAgeInput,
      String childDiagnosisInput,
      String childPicUrl) async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(parentUid)
        .collection('children')
        .doc(childUid)
        .set({
      'childName': childNameInput,
      'childAge': childAgeInput,
      'childDiagnosis': childDiagnosisInput,
      'childUid': childUid,
      'childPicUrl': childPicUrl,
    });
  } // writes children details to db

  Future<String> uploadImageToFirebase(String childUid, File img) async {
    Reference storage = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('users/$parentIdGlobal/$childUid/child_pic');
    UploadTask uploadTask = storage.putFile(img);

    var dowurl = await (await uploadTask).ref.getDownloadURL();
    var url = dowurl.toString();
    return url;
  }

  _showAddDialog() {
    String? childUid = Uuid().v4();
    String? childNameInput;
    String? childAgeInput;
    String? childDiagnosisInput;
    String? childPicUrl;
    File? pickedImage;
    bool imgStatus = true;
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setState) => AlertDialog(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              10.0,
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(
            'Add Child Information',
          ),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          elevation: 10.0,
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
```

Here is my image path portion. My image appears in the dialogue box, but it does not print or upload to the Firebase Cloud.

```
GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () async {
                      await Permission.photos.request();
                      var status = await Permission.photos.status;
                      if (status.isGranted) {
                        XFile? _pickedImage = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
                          source: ImageSource.gallery,
                          maxWidth: 100,
                          maxHeight: 100,
                        );
                        if (_pickedImage != null) {
                          pickedImage = File(_pickedImage.path);
                          setState(() {
                            imgStatus = true;
                          });
                        }
                      } else if (status.isDenied ||
                          status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
                        showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (context) {
                              if (Platform.isAndroid)
                                return AlertDialog(
                                  title: Text('Permission Not Granted'),
                                  content: Text(
                                      'The permission for photo library is not granted'),
                                  actions: [
                                    TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () => openAppSettings(),
                                      child: Text('Ok'),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              return CupertinoAlertDialog(
                                title: Text('Permission Not Granted'),
                                content: Text(
                                    'The permission for photo library is not granted'),
                                actions: [
                                  TextButton(
                                    onPressed: () => openAppSettings(),
                                    child: Text('Ok'),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              );
                            });
                      }
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 10.0,
                        bottom: 10.0,
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 100.0,
                        width: 100.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          border: Border.all(
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: pickedImage == null
                            ? Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        )
                            : Image.file(
                          pickedImage!,
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                childNameController.clear();
                childAgeController.clear();
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Text('Cancel'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: imgStatus
                ?() async {
                childNameInput = childNameController.text;
                childAgeInput = childAgeController.text;
                childDiagnosisInput = childDiagnosisController.text;

                String parentUid = await getData('parentUid') ?? '';

                if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? true) {
                  if (pickedImage != null) {
                    childPicUrl =
                    await uploadImageToFirebase(childUid, pickedImage!);
                  }

                  await writeChildrenToDb(parentUid, childUid, childNameInput!,
                      childAgeInput!, childDiagnosisInput!, childPicUrl!);
                  childNameController.clear();
                  childAgeController.clear();
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                }
              }: null,
              child: Text('Ok'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

security rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check Internet Permission in Manifest file

Comment: I did , I added Permissions in my manifest

Comment: add permission manually from your device then restart the app . hope now it will work